How can I implement individual page breaks for each question in a webform with a dynamic progress tracker?
I am working with a Drupal 10 project, and have set up a webform that includes multiple groups of questions. My webform is structured into the following six groups:

Intro

question 1
question 2
question 3
question 4


Data

question 1
question 2


Research

question 1
question 2
question 3


Aim

question 1
question 2
question 3


Method

question 1
question 2
question 3


Review

question 1
question 2
question 3



Each group contains a varying number of questions (from 1 to n). The default functionality of the progress tracker in Drupal easily handles showing progress across these six groups.
However, I have a specific requirement that I'm struggling to implement.
I would like to insert a page break after every question within each group, so that each question appears on a separate sub-page. Additionally, I want the progress tracker to dynamically update to show the current question of the current group as active, similar to the following format.

Intro
1 - 2 - 3 - 4
Data
1 - 2
Research
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5

So far, I have experimented with using cards and field groups but haven't achieved the desired outcome. The main challenges are:

Dynamically creating page breaks after each question
Correctly updating the progress tracker to highlight the current question

Is there a way to customize the webform?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Are you writing custom JavaScript to do this?

@monalisa i might end up with that, if nothing else is possible
